# Is it possible to calculate the odds for a one more goal to be scored in the first half from the odds of the teams winning the first half?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, bessel-functions, gambling

Let's say that at `35 minutes` of the first half in one Bookmaker we find the following odds for the first half result:

```
Team A: 4.50  
Draw: 1.33  
Team B: 9.50

Score: 1-1
```

Is it possible to calculate the odds for a one more goal to be scored in the first half?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Presumably those odds take the results of the first $35$ minutes into account, right?  And I have no guess what the "Over $.5$ Goals HT marker" might mean.

Comment: Hi @lulu I edited my text a little because it was confusing, but the doubt was whether only with the odds to win the first half, if it would be possible to calculate the probability that at least one more goal would still happen in the first half.

Comment: As I mentioned, we'd need to know the score at that point.  Also, we'd need to distinguish ties of the form $0-0$ from other ties.

Comment: I have a more basic problem. What are the *real* probabilities of the "A wins", "B wins" and "it's a draw"? Those odds supposedly tell me what the bookmaker is *thinking* the odds are, but even then, $\frac{1}{4.50}+\frac{1}{1.33}+\frac{1}{9.50}$ don't add up to $1$. So, how do we fudge those three numbers to find at least what the bookmaker thinks are the real probabilities?

Comment: @StinkingBishop  Odds are not probabilities, though one can translate back and forth.  To get probabilities, divide by the sum.  Thus the probability that $A$ wins is $\frac {4.5}{4.5+1.33+9.5}$ and so on. Of course the probability of a given outcome ($A$ wins, $B$ wins, or tie) is not trivially linked to the probability of a goal occurring over the remaining ten minutes of play.

Comment: @lulu I would be able to add the score to facilitate the calculation, in this case it would be 1 goals to Team A and 1 goals to Team B, score 1-1.

Comment: It's not a matter of  facilitating the calculation...the information you want simply isn't determined by the data.  If the score is $1-1$, for instance, we know that a goal must happen in order for either $A$ or $B$ to win.  However, we can achieve a tie either by having no further score or by having both times score the same number of goals.

Comment: To be sure:  in a real world situation, with such little time remaining in the half, you might well want to assume that at most one more goal can occur in the half.  If so, then (given that the current score is $1-1$) the answer you want is the sum of the probabilities for the two victories.  But that's an assumption you must make...it's not a mathematical observation.

Comment: @lulu Converting odds to probabilities may violate Kolmogorov's axioms.  Bookmakers are interested in minimizing risk, not estimating probabilities.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Oh, sure.  I'm ignoring any spreads and such.  If that information is known, it is easy to incorporate.  Or we could make some plausible guesses.  But, yes.  I'm assuming that the book maker is a neutral estimator of probabilities.

Comment: @lulu Why are you assuming that?  Suppose that you are a bookie in Barcelona and I am a bookie in Madrid. The locals bet mostly on the local team. We start with the same initial odds, but then our odds diverge because of our own risk-minimisation. Arbitrageurs then take advantage of this divergence and provide a force for convergence.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  I'm assuming that because we have no information regarding the spread(s), and because that assumption doesn't materially alter the primary conclusion (that there isn't really enough information provided).  As I said, it's easy to model the spread which, for most bets, is modest.  Granted, deep out of the money bets are likely to have great giant spreads taken out of them and that complicates the modeling.  But, really, all of this goes far beyond the scope of the OP's question, no?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Oh, perhaps I am misreading your objection.  Maybe you aren't speaking of spreads but just local biases in small markets.  But of course, we have even less information regarding that in  this problem.  If we want to have any hope of proceeding, we must assume that the market is deep enough so that bookmakers can easily clear any risk (up to a modest spread).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  See my most recent comment Yes, I thought you were talking about spreads but  I worked out that you are just talking about biases in small markets.  But, surely, you agree that we aren't given enough information to sort out the risks in this particular book, right?  Let's just assume that the market is deep enough so that the bookkeeper can clear risk very cheaply.

Comment: This is above my knowledge, but what I can tell is that the *number of goals* scored by Team A can probably be modelled as a Poisson distribution with an unknown parameter $\mu_1$ (i.e. $P(\text{Team A scores exactly }n\text{ goals}=e^{-\mu_1}\frac{\mu_1^n}{n!}$). The same for Team B and unknown parameter $\mu_2$. Now the *goal difference*, assuming goals of Team A and Team B are independent, follows Skellam distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution ) with parameters $\mu_1,\mu_2$. The probabilities of Team A winning, a draw, Team A losing are, in fact, the probabilities

Comment: ... of $\text{Skellam}(\mu_1,\mu_2)>0$,$\text{Skellam}(\mu_1,\mu_2)=0$ and $\text{Skellam}(\mu_1,\mu_2)<0$. It could be maybe possible to calculate $\mu_1, \mu_2$ knowing those three probabilities ... but I cannot follow it through myself. Perhaps someone else can? (Of course, if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are known, calculating the probability that anyone will score at all becomes trivial.) I've edited the tags hoping that it will attract more people.